# How to demonstrate android app on website?

Tags: android, emulation

Does anyone know of an easy way to present an android app through a website? Maybe the equivalent of an emulator running on a webpage. It would be great for demonstrating app functionality via the web and doing basic initial customer design approval without them having to install an app. It would also be good for marketing existing apps.

Comment: Create a video of your application. I don't think that there would be a web based Android emulator anytime soon.

Comment: were none of our answers any good?

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a video is the best way. If you are on a mac, try this:

[Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm)

If you are on Windows, try this:

[Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/)

I use ScreenFlow and then put the video on my website for clients to see.

Comment: For windows i use Camstudio (open source :D) and upload it to youtube

Comment: Any equivalent solution for linux ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Droid VNC Server](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&feature=search_result) on your own handset and connect an android handset to your Network, then give them a webpage with the HTML web viewer of Droid VNC server. That would probably give you the best solution and would be transparent for the customer.

Comment: To make it further interesting, you could use the Droid VNC server on a headless virtual machine, so you can access it via the HTTP port redirection facility of your perimetral firewall (Reverse NAT on IPTables speak). This would probably work like a charm.

Comment: Hello. I am curious. How do you access DVNCS' web viewer?

Answer (score 1):

Do this

1. Install the ADB Driver to directly debug the app in Android Phone
2. Open Android Studio, directly run your app in Android phone.
3. Click the Capture icon. its capture the screenshot of android phone.

4.See the images , Android Studio have own Screenshoter, Video Recorder.

5.No Need of Third party Softwares.

Hope this helpful.

Happy Coding :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android being based on Java, I guess one could adapt the emulator for a webbrowser version, but this would be quite long, and inefficient.

If you forced your user to download the emulator (you could package it without the whole sdk), you could make a batch script to launch it and install your apk, but for a lambda user this would be too much trouble to test one app.

The only solutions left are

1. making a video of your app's features (you could then add subtitles and graphic design to enhance a point in the video)
2. make a fake version using flash or HTML5 / javascript
3. make a java applet (you could then reuse some of your code, and only redesign the GUI)

Comment: The emulator is done as a virtual machine emulating an ARM architecture, with Native code, no way to put it on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommed using TeamViewer or other simmilar remote access/remote desktop sharing solution.
Teamviewer is free.

ps.
i know this is not on webpage, but i figure if you'll be presenting this could be a good option.